Timing for USB-PD comms on CC line for USB-C?
I am working on a peripheral / powered device that will utilize USB-C power.  I am planning on using an ADC to monitor the Rd voltage in order to determine how much current the device can use and adapt accordingly.  I only intend to pull a maximum of 1.5A @ 5V if it is available, so I am just monitoring Rd to change that the source is capable of providing the current after startup.  The device can operate at the default 0.5A current if needed (so hooking it up to a USB 2.0 port is OK) but would operate better with higher current.
I don't think I need a Full USB-PD device (supporting all the COMMS protocol on the CC line).  But we have use cases that would support running the device off of any USB-C charger.  I am concerned about someone hooking up a charger that supports USB-PD and want to avoiding making ADC measurements while it is transmitting its capability messages on the CC line from the USB-PD protocol.
Given I don't intend to respond to any USB-PD messages, I am assuming:

The USB-PD device only advertises once, doesn't get a response, and stays at the Default USB-C negotiated power scheme.
There is some sort of requirement on how long after power on that negotiation has to happen (and I can just avoid that window).

Is there any sort of timing diagram around USB-PD comms during initialization that would help here?  I've been staring at the USB-PD and USB-C specs for a while.  It's not super clear to me how to monitor that voltage if a USB-PD could be pumping message on it.

Have you considered to use a professionally-designed CC-controller  such as TUSB320HAI or similar?

@Ale..chenski I had, but it wasn't clear if this device would be compatible with USB-PD devices (like a charger) sending comms over the CC lines.  I guess if I assume it should be OK then this kind of device would work just fine.

Its job is to be compatible with other USB-C devices and handle all the CC communication for you.
